# call jsTree inside jquery

Tags: jquery, jstree

First,I am novice programmer in jQuery.
I want to make a Tree structure out of unordered List in HTML.I came across that jsTree can be used to it.So,I wrote this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jstree.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#fileLister").jstree();

});

</script>

</head>
<body>


    <div id="fileLister">
        <ul>
            <li><a>Folder A</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a>Child 1</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a>Child A</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a>Child B</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a>Child C</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul></li>
                    <li><a>Child 2</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a>Child D</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul></li>
    </ul></li>
    </ul>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

But its not printing it in a folder tree strucutre..rather only folder A is printed and nothing apart from it on the web page.

Comment: I want to do it using jquery and jsTree

Comment: Click on "Folder A" (first node), the children will appear. Your code works fine, see http://jsfiddle.net/ruCdP/

Comment: Thnx...so silly :(
For the folder icons what should I do??

Comment: You should include the CSS file as well for the folders to appear